# Invocations Graph in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

As per documentation, Invocation graph shows:-

> Measures the number of times a function is invoked in response to an
>   event or invocation API call. This replaces the deprecated
>   RequestCount metric. This includes successful and failed invocations,
>   but does not include throttled attempts. This equals the billed
>   requests for the function. Note that AWS Lambda only sends these
>   metrics to CloudWatch if they have a nonzero value.

But this count is per second or per minute? It does not say anything. Can someone tell that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most granular metric appears to be per minute.

Comment: I think its actually per second. Its just that static should be average to see what TPS one is getting.